# Append property to JSON object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table in MySQL whose column user_json holds a JSON value like this..

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName":"Rizzo"
  },
  "city":"Salisbury"
}
```

I want to add an email address property to the existing JSON so the result should look like..

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName":"Rizzo",
    "emailAddress":"joeR@gmail.com"
  },
  "city":"Salisbury"
}
```

I thought I could use JSON_INSERT like so....

```
update my_table set user_json = 
JSON_INSERT(user_json, '$. user', JSON_OBJECT("emailAddress","joeR@gmail.com")) where id = 4783
```

But this didn't update the JSON. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try with JSON_MERGE_PATCH , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch

Answer (score 3):

**Updated 2022-03-15**

I believe [JSON_INSERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-insert) accepts a key-value pair (where the `path` is the key). So you don't need JSON_OBJECT(). Instead try:

```
 UPDATE YourTable  
 SET    user_json = JSON_INSERT(user_json
                           , '$.user.emailAddress'
                           , 'joeR@gmail.com')
 WHERE  id = 4783
```

**Results:**

```
{
  "city": "Salisbury",
  "user": {
    "lastName": "Rizzo",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "emailAddress": "joeR@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a8f9215349fef251c457dcb6c6074d9)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted the emailAddress property to be inside the nested 'user' object as I had in the OP above. Could we do that with JSON_INSERT()?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just change the path to `$.user.emailAddress`.