# Add to json in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How add to json varible a new element in mySQL

From this:
Value = ['123']
Make this:
Value = ['123','456']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append property to JSON object in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474289/append-property-to-json-object-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

[JSON_ARRAY_APPEND() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append)

```
SET @Value = '["123"]';
SET @Value = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@Value, '$', '456');
SELECT @Value;
```

| @Value |
| --- |
| ["123", "456"] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F1rb-mCF)